# How to start linux gui before login?

Tags: boot, cinnamon, unity

When my system (Kali 2 or Ubuntu 14) boots and I login, I have to wait for the gui(cinnamon/unity) to load. How to avoid it starting to load gui before login like windows does?

I mean, when I get to the login screen and log in, I have to wait for the whole GUI to load (Desktop, menu and files), more than 10 seconds. The thing is that even if I get the GUI login screen after boot, and I wait for about a minute and then login, I still have to wait for it to load.

So, how can I preload this GUI (desktop, menus, files) so that when I log in it is fully loaded and just works?

Comment: How would you want to login without the GUI? You can disable the GUI and present just a plain text login if that's what you want, but I suspect it's not. Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean.

Comment: @roaima, already

Comment: There's a daemon that does that. It's called exactly like that: [preload](http://sourceforge.net/projects/preload/) (should be available from your distro repositories). Even better: buy a SSD, they're cheap nowadays. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely set by grub, assuming you're hitting the text console first. You may be able to fix it with:

```
# nano /etc/default/grub

Change the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" 

**Update Grub**

# update-grub
```

Reboot and you should hit the GUI login.

Comment: @user299572 And what if I just don't have this file in /etc/default?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install a SSD drive to your computer in order to load everything in 10 seconds.

A way of having everything  what you want preloaded inside a `non-volatile` memory device, such as `HDD` or `SDD`, is using `hibernation`.